# How can this ASP.NET site runs with only ASP.aspx and ASP.ascx and not .cs class?

Tags: asp.net

I downloaded and installed screwturn wiki 
http://www.screwturn.eu/

Looking in directories I can only see ASP.aspx and ASP.ascx files no cs file whereas there is reference to ascx.cs like

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PageSelector.ascx.cs" Inherits="ScrewTurn.Wiki.PageSelector" %>
```

So how can it run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cs files are compiled into a dll, usually in the \bin directory.